# Limit Infimum of Sequence of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be some random variables on $(\Omega, F, P)$. Let $X = \liminf X_i$. How do I prove that $P(X \leq 1) \leq \liminf P(X_i \leq 1)$?

The statement reminds me of Fatou’s Lemma, but I just cannot come with any reasonable way to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Take $X_i=1+\frac1 i$ and $X=1$. Then $P(X \leq 1)=1$ but $P(X_i \leq 1)=0$ for all $i$.